# Issue with Nginx SSL config 301 http to https

Tags: nginx, ssl, chrome, safari

my default server config is :

```
# redirection http://example.org vers https//example.org
#
server {
    server_name example.org;
    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}

# redirection http ou https www.example.org vers https ou https example.org
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-example.org.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name www.example.org;
    return 301 $scheme://example.org$request_uri;
}

#bloc server https://example.org
#
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    include snippets/ssl-example.org.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name example.org;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

        location ~/.well-known {
            allow all;
        }
}
```

Accessing directly https://example.org or https://www.example.org is fine

BUT when I try http access 
   http://example.org or http://www.example.org , I get

```
This page isn’t working
example.org didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I checked with curl

```
$ curl -Iv http://example.org
* Rebuilt URL to: http://example.org/
*   Trying 138.197.100.98...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.org (138.197.100.98) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
```

No 301 return

My ssl-params.conf file is :

```
# from https://cipherli.st/
# and https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
 # Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
# the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
 #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

what's wrong with my config ?
note: I am using AVAST anti-virus,  Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) or Safari Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4).. same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should  add here 'listen' directive

```
server {
    server_name example.org;
    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}
```

and replace '$scheme' for 'https' here(because if $scheme == http you redirected to http. Where is the sense?)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-example.org.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name www.example.org;
    return 301 $scheme://example.org$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback . ...  If I had a listen 80 iwithin the first block , I have a double definition (?)
And the $scheme in the second block is only for www.example.org, this block is running fine...   As only http://example.com is a problem I guess it's related to HSTS directive ... which may be blocking http requests... I'll check that

Comment: Exctly - commenting the HSTS directive in my ssl-params.conf file did it , it's now running fine with http://example.com